# Is it possible to pause Protractor runtime and inspect local vars?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

Is it possible to set a breakpoint (for example) on a line inside a test and be allowed to inspect local vars in Chrome Dev Tools, like you normally can with JavaScript applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, [Debugging Protractor Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) pretty extensively explains how to debug your tests.

Basically, you need to insert `browser.debugger();` line in the place you want to start debugging and run protractor in `debug` mode:

```
protractor debug
```